# Django не видит метод модели в миграции

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Модель получаю через

```py
apps.get_model()
```

В миграции используется метод `get_period_by_date`, который у модели имеется, НО
Вылезает вот это:

```
Applying group.0043_update_empty_values... 
period = Period.get_period_by_date(group.date_from, group.date_to)
AttributeError: type object 'Period' has no attribute 'get_period_by_date'
```

Comment: Код модели в студию, код миграции в студию

Comment: Period.objects.get_period_by_date(group.date_from, group.date_to) пробовали?